# Online apps in Metro

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, c#-5.0

I would like to make an app that get data from web site for windows 8 Metro which I already have a couple of offline apps there ,but I really don't have an idea where to start and what to study to know with online applications.
Should I learn WCF or ASP.Net or something else?
I know this didn't work with Metro but I just wanna to learn the best way to work with servers from an app.

My programming language is C#.
Thnx.

Comment: Did you just throw in a bunch of acronyms without actually knowing what they are?

Comment: @millimoose I looked at WCF last night and I think it will be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF is overkill and is on the way out anyway - SOAP is dead, long-live REST!

Anyway, depending on what web-service you want to talk to you can use either a pre-written client or write your own. If it's a RESTful service then you can easily write your own client using `HttpWebRequest`, if it's a SOAP/WCF service then you'll probably want to use VS's client proxy generator to save you the pain.

...and yes, all this works with Metro (or rather, Tifkam) because you can do it in pure C# using classes made available to these kinds of applications.

Comment: I spent last night looking in some books about WCF and it looks very useful. It has some useful binding types with SOAP but I also wanna to look in your suggestion HttpWebRequest do you know which book should I use to get some useful info abiut it? Big thanks to you.

Comment: This is a terrible, fact-free, opinionated answer. You don't even try to address *why* one would choose SOAP or REST or WCF, and there are certainly reasons to favour one over the other depending on the use case. WCF can be used to back a JSON service accessible over plain HTTP just fine. If you're developing an API meant for internal consumption, WCF's client generation will likely save you effort over using not-SOAP, and still let you expose an endpoint for, say, an iOS client where SOAP is less convenient. Also, `HttpClient` is probably a better choice for API clients than `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time. To get all what you say I need first to get my hand dirty and try some examples to understand what is SOAP and what is REST so pardon me if I didn't ask the right question. I hope this week I can digest this expression to chose what good for me.